# ionic react firebase otp text customization

Tags: mobile

I managed to get the Phone authentication successfully on android and ios. But the OT message always in the format mentioned below

> OTP SMS  "123342 is your verification code for localhost"

How do I get rid of localhost or add my own text?

I' wrote the code in Ionic React

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . You haven't provided enough informations.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this ?